# Constructive proof of how many trees on $[n]$ have exactly $3$ vertices with degree $3$ and all other vertices with degree $\leq 2$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How many trees on $[n]$ have exactly $3$ vertices with degree $3$ and all other vertices degree $\leq 2$?

I argued from prufer codes and got that there must be $\displaystyle \frac{(n-3)!}{5!}\binom{n-2}{2}\binom{n-4}{2}\binom{n-6}{2}$. I am unsure whether this result is correct (would err on the side of saying not) - however I am interested in seeing a constructive approach to this problem (i.e. by constructing trees). Can't get very far with my attempt but I think I can picture the solution.

Comment: Are we counting labeled trees, or are we counting isomorphism classes of unlabeled trees?

Answer (score 1):

With Pruefer codes being mentioned it appears we are counting labeled
trees. Using these codes we get from first principles

$${n\choose 3}
\times {n-2\choose 2} {n-4\choose 2} {n-6\choose 2}
\times {n-3\choose n-8} \times (n-8)!.$$

This simplifies to

$${n\choose 3} \times
\frac{(n-2)!}{8} \times {n-3\choose n-8}
\\ = \frac{1}{8} \frac{n!}{n(n-1)}
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} {n-3\choose n-8}
= \frac{1}{8} n! {n-2\choose n-8}.$$

Counting by constructing trees we have the following structure which
has eight automorphisms (Tour Eiffel):

```
          o
          |
          |
          |
          |
          o
         / \
        /   \
       o     o
      / \   / \
     o   o o   o
```

Here we  distribute zero or  more nodes on  the edges. This  gives the
generating function  (leading coefficient, automorphisms,  first term,
structure nodes, second term, nodes on top edge, third term, nodes on
second level edges, fourth term, nodes on third level edges)

$$\frac{1}{8} \times z^8 \times
\frac{1}{1-z} \times \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \times
\frac{1}{(1-z)^4}
= \frac{1}{8} \frac{z^8}{(1-z)^7}.$$

Extracting the coefficient on $[z^n]$ we find (these are EGFs)

$$\frac{1}{8} n! [z^{n-8}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^7}
= \frac{1}{8} n! {n-2\choose n-8}.$$

This is the same as what the Pruefer codes produced.
Here we have repeatedly used the combinatorial class for sequences
namely

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=8}(\mathcal{Z})
\quad\text{and}\quad
\textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 0}(\mathcal{Z})
\quad\text{which has EGF} \quad
z^8 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

**Addendum.** We can also solve the corresponding unlabeled problem.
This requires the cycle index of the edges under the automorphism group
of the structure graph. We get from first principles that

$$Z(E) = \frac{1}{8} (a_1^7 + 2 a_1^5 a_2 + a_1^3 a_2^2
+ 2 a_1 a_2^3 + 2 a_1 a_2 a_4).$$

We thus obtain for $n\ge 8$

$$\frac{1}{8} [z^n] z^8
\left(\frac{1}{(1-z)^7} + 2 \frac{1}{(1-z)^5} \frac{1}{1-z^2}
+ \frac{1}{(1-z)^3} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^2}
\\ + 2 \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^3}
+ 2 \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-z^2} \frac{1}{1-z^4}\right).$$

This simplifies to

$$z^8 \frac{1 - z + 2z^2}{(1 - z)^7(1 + z)^3(1 + z^2)}.$$

This gives the following sequence starting at $n=8:$

$$1, 3, 10, 24, 55, 109, 206, 360, 606, 970, 
1508, 2264, 3322, \ldots$$

These may be verified with the following NAUTY / Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub decode_graph {
    my ($str) = @_;

    sub R {
        my (@args) = map {
            sprintf "%06b", $_;
        } @_;
        join '', @args;
    }

    my (@ents) = map {
        ord($_) - 63 
    } split //, $str;

    my $n = shift @ents;
    my @adj_data = split //, R(@ents);

    my $adj = []; my $pos = 0;
    for(my $ind2 = 1; $ind2 < $n; $ind2++){
        for(my $ind1 = 0; $ind1 < $ind2; $ind1++){
            $adj->[$ind1]->[$ind2] = $adj_data[$pos];
            $adj->[$ind2]->[$ind1] = $adj_data[$pos];

            $pos++;
        }
    }

    return $adj;
}

MAIN: {
    my $mx = shift || 2;
    die "out of range for GENG: $mx" 
        if $mx < 2 || $mx > 32;

    for(my $n=2; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my $cmd = sprintf "../nauty26r7/geng -c %d %d",
        $n, $n-1;

        my $count = 0;

        open GENG, "$cmd 2>/dev/null|";
        while(my $tree = <GENG>){
            chomp $tree; my $adj = decode_graph $tree;

            my $vd3 = 0;
            
            my $v;
            for($v = 0; $v < $n; $v++){
                my $deg = 0;
                for(my $w = 0; $w < $n; $w++){
                    my $ent = $adj->[$v]->[$w];
                    $deg++ if defined($ent) && $ent == 1;
                }

                last if $deg > 3;
                if($deg == 3){
                    $vd3++;
                    last if $vd3 > 3;
                }
            }

            $count++ if $v == $n && $vd3 == 3;
        }
        close GENG;

        print "$count\n";
    }
}
```